# MSG 156, Level 15, State 1 when CREATE VIEW (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

When I try to create a view, I get the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure viewFangst2021, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 445]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

I do not understand what is wrong with the code. The same thing happens if I am going to create a procedure.

Could it have something to do with settings or such in SQL? for this happens regardless of whether I create a view

```
CREATE VIEW viewFangst2021 
AS
    SELECT 
        FISK.FiskeNr, FISK.Fiskeslag, 
        COUNT(*) AS Antall, 
        ROUND(AVG(Vekt), 1) AS [Gjennomsnittsvekt (kg)] 
    FROM 
        FANGST, FISK 
    WHERE 
        FANGST.FiskeNr = FISK.FiskeNr 
        AND YEAR (Dato) = 2021 
    GROUP BY 
        FISK.FiskeNr, FISK.Fiskeslag 

    SELECT * 
    FROM viewFangst2021
```

Comment: You cant have 2 separate SELECT statements in a view, that's what the error is telling you

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You are trying to select from the view in the same batch as where you create the view. This is not allowed. If this in SSMS put a `GO` between the statements so they are in separate batches

Comment: I recommend against syntax like `YEAR (Dato) = 2021 ` in the `WHERE` as well; this isn't SARGable. Use proper date boundaries: `Dato >= '20210101' AND Dato < '20220101'`